# Communicating with HID USB device from a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, usb, hid

I've got a microcontroller unit and I need to connect it to PC via USB. I've already created its HID descriptor and it's up and running on Windows but I need a C#/WPF application to communicate with it (Read/Write). There's no built-in library for USB in C# (.NET) so I searched the web long enough but can't find a way to perform this task. I found many solutions on Github but they don't seem to work with me. Could anyone help me with a USB library that's straightforward and easy to use? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking out this library https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=simplehidlibrary
This one has a demo app and also references other solutions for communicating with HID devices.

If these don't work for you, you can still write your own implementation using P/Invoke based on official HID API documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/introduction-to-hid-concepts

Happy hacking!